# I need to Parse a XMLString using only serverside scripting

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, server-side

I need to parse a XML String so I can use some of the elements in my script but I can only use server-side programing.

Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)(if parsing xml string)  or [simplexml_load_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)